# Spring Boot: Multiple Datasources | Not able to read Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The spring boot program is as below:

```
package com.te.initializer;
@SpringBootApplication
public class WWWAbacusApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WWWAbacusApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Datasource Configuration is multiple:

```
package com.te.configuration;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application-dev.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.te.repository.www", entityManagerFactoryRef = "wwwEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "wwwTransactionManager")
@Profile("dev")
public class WWWDBConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public WWWDBConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean wwwEntityManager() {
        System.out.println("Entity Manager Creation");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.te.repository.www" });
        System.out.println("Entity Manager Creation Vendor");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        System.out.println("Entity Manager Creation EM Initiated");
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource userDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager wwwTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(wwwEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Similarly Another configuration is craeated with only difference is base package in com.te.repository.masterdata and cofiguration properties as "spring.md-datasource"

In properties file, It looks like

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@1xx.1xx.65.1x6:1521/xxxPROD9
spring.datasource.username=int
spring.datasource.password=inte
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.md-datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@daq-e-ora01.cosng.net:1521/ir_qa
spring.md-datasource.username=MASTERDATA
spring.md-datasource.password=ykw3
spring.md-datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl=update
#spring.jpa.database-platform=

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When i run this application i get :

```
2022-06-30 23:08:25.642  INFO 30432 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-06-30 23:08:26.862  INFO 30432 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-30 23:08:26.895  INFO 30432 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
```

Followed this -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Entities are also proper annotated and things work fine with single db.

Not sure where the issue is there? Is something missing in Main Application or packaging issue?

Comment: Maybe you should consider adding more detail to receive some help (as in: sharing the other configuration)

Comment: Remove the `@PropertySource` and `@Profile` and move your `WWWAbacusApplication` to the `com.te` else it won't detect the `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes that was issue. I have already added (scanBasePackages = "com.te") to fixed this